# Implement search filter for multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement search in multidimensional array.

This is my array

var data= [ [1, "TEST", "0", "110"], ["2", "row2", "0", "111"],[3, "Test1", "0", "113"]];

Below is the code:

```
var data= [ [1, "TEST", "0", "110"], ["2", "row2", "0", "111"],[3, "Test1", "0", "113"]];

arrayFilter(array, value) {
 return array.filter(function (object) {
    return Object.keys(object).some(function (key) {
        return object[key.toLowerCase()]===(value.toLowerCase()); 
    });
});
}
console.log(this.arrayFilter(data,test)
```

This function returns [1, "TEST", "0", "110"]

I want it to return partial match also. i.e it should return [[1, "TEST", "0", "110"],[3, "Test1", "0", "113"]]

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is the fillter criteria?

Comment: Use Pattern and Matcher

Comment: @brijesh I'm pretty sure `Pattern` and `Matcher` only exist in Java, the Java tag here was wrongly placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `test1` is not equals `test`;

instead of `===`, you can use includes

```
let arrayFilterFn = (arrayToFilter, value) => {
    return arrayToFilter.filter(subArray => {
        return subArray.some(v => {
            v = v+''; // convert number to string
            return v.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        })
    })
}
```